# Google sheets extract the last part of path file

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have this data in Google Sheets cells:

```
Dom\SKUto\ctures\VN_0001.png
Dom\SKUto\ctures\sinom\VN_0002.JPG
Dom\SKUto\ctures\folder\VN_0003.jpg
pictures\folder\VN_0004.jpg
```

I want to return in another cell only the last part of it (the picture name and extension)

```
VN_0001.png
VN_0002.JPG
VN_0003.jpg
VN_0004.jpg
```

How do I do that in Google Sheets?

Comment: Does this help  ```=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",100)),99))```? You haven't mentioned which tool to use.

Comment: Hi Serge, no it doesn't work. I use google sheets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try the following formula

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE(Q2:Q,"(.*\\)(.*)$","$2"))
```

**OR**

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(Q2:Q="",,(REGEXEXTRACT(Q2:Q,".*\\(.*)$"))))
```

*(adjust ranges to your needs)*

[image]

Comment: Definitly did ;)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to accept and upvoting as well.